# Displaying SVG in Offline(no network) mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, networking

Whenever there is no internet connection I want to display an SVG, but the problem is that the SVG is not loading in **offline** mode.
I am using **react-detect-offline** library to detect network (Offline/Online).

Is there any way to **preload** the SVG or using SVG in offline mode in javascript or **React**.

```
 <Offline>
     <OfflineContainer
         offlineMessage="It looks like you're offline. We'll keep trying to reconnect."
         iconSVG={this.props.iconSVG}
     />
</Offline>
```

The offline message is displayed properly but the
**SVG** does not load whenever I go offline.

P.S- I am sending SVG as a prop to my offline component.

Comment: you can just inline the SVG code

Comment: I have a separate component for SVG don't wanna use it inline.

Comment: so is your SVG part of local "assets" or you are getting it from an online resource?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko its part of my local assets but still not loading when going offline

Answer (score 1):

Use the service worker to cache the svg. Include svg with prefetch attribute to load it even if not needed. Then, when your service worker runs, even without active connection, you can access the svg.